# Operacion para sacar porcentaje SQL

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(FLOAT,22*100) / 148)
```

Con ella obtengo un porcentaje = 14.8648648648649

Este porcentaje lo tengo que mostrar en mi aplicación web pero de la siguiente manera porcentaje = 14.86, solo mostrando los ultimos dos decimales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `CAST`, para convertirlo a tipo numérico (`numeric`) con solo dos (2) decimales.

```
SELECT CAST((CONVERT(FLOAT,22*100) / 148) as numeric(36,2))
```

> as numeric(x,2), con x <= 38

---

Alternativa:

`ROUND( valorARedondear ,2)`, pero podría devolverte mas de 2 decimales, dependiendo los tipo de datos si usas parámetros obtenidos con una `query`.

Answer (score 0):

con la funcion `ROUND(numero, decimal)` puedes redondear el valor, quedaria asi

```
SELECT (ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,22*100) / 148), 2)
```

Espero te sirva ReNiceCode...